# How to show EC2 instance summary report?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

After connecting to an EC2 instance via SSH I get a nice summary report shown - the one you find below. Is it possible to display this report with a command?

```
➜  ~ ssh ...
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'example.net' differs from the key for the IP address '12.34.56.78'
Offending key for IP in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:30
Matching host key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:66
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon Feb  6 10:03:28 UTC 2017

  System load:  0.66               Processes:           155
  Usage of /:   43.0% of 49.08GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 1%                 IP address for eth0: 172.12.34.56
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

10 packages can be updated.
10 updates are security updates.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Mon Feb  6 09:20:51 2017 from 31.19.89.2
ubuntu@ip-172-12-34-56:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that "report" is an Ubuntu specific dynamic version of the traditional MOTD (message of the day) login message that gets generated with [`update-motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/update-motd.5.html).

You can simply access that report by reading the file `/var/run/motd`

From the manual:

> UNIX/Linux system adminstrators often communicate important information
>          to console and remote users by maintaining text in the file  `/etc/motd`,
>          which  is  displayed  by  the  pam_motd(8)  module on interactive shell
>          logins.
>
> Traditionally, this file is static text,  typically  installed  by  the
>          distribution  and  only  updated on release upgrades, or overwritten by
>          the local administrator with pertinent information.
>
> Ubuntu introduced the update-motd framework, by which  the  motd(5)  is
>   dynamically assembled from a collection of scripts at login.
>
> Executable  scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/*` are executed by pam_motd(8)
>   as the root user at each login, and this information is concatenated in
>   `/var/run/motd`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. There are in fact some scripts. The one bellow displays system information like load, memory, swap etc

```
/usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper
```

The other scripts can be found on this location:

```
/etc/update-motd.d
```

Here is a full list with them:

```
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1220 Feb 20  2014 00-header
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1358 Feb 20  2014 10-help-text
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   46 Jan 14  2016 50-landscape-sysinfo -> /usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  334 Jan 14  2016 51-cloudguest
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  149 Aug 22  2011 90-updates-available
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  299 Nov 13  2014 91-release-upgrade
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  129 Aug  5  2016 95-hwe-eol
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  111 Jun  3  2015 97-overlayroot
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  142 Aug 22  2011 98-fsck-at-reboot
4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  144 Aug 22  2011 98-reboot-required
```